# Can we install/side-load outlook custom add-in for Mac programatically without manually installing

Tags: macos, install, ms-office, microsoft

Is there a way to install outlook custom add-ins in Mac from terminal without requiring manually installation.From outlook documentation https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/sideload-outlook-add-ins-for-testing we have to do it manually by selecting file from Get Add-ins --> My Add-ins ->Add from a file.

For example for word we copy manifest file in to a predefined location and that appears in my add-ins. Is there anything similar for Outlook?

Comment: Did you reach out to Microsoft Support on this already?

Comment: I second @nohillside - there are so many builds of outlook, the target shifts quite regularly. Here is where I try to keep track of which version does what... https://macadmins.software/

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to install outlook custom add-ins in Mac from terminal without requiring manually installation.

Yes.  From Microsoft Documentation:

[Sideload Office Add-ins on iPad and Mac for testing](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/sideload-an-office-add-in-on-ipad-and-mac)

For side loading the add-on in Office for Mac, you need to save/copy the manifest file to the `wef` folder. If the folder doesn't exist, you must create it.

- Word: `/Users/<username>/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Word/Data/Documents/wef`
- Excel: `/Users/<username>/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data/Documents/wef`
- PowerPoint: `/Users/<username>/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Powerpoint/Data/Documents/wef`

Comment: I tried copying manifest file to com.microsoft.outlook, but that didnt worked.

Comment: These are Microsoft's instructions.  If you have something not working, then it may not be compatible or you need to contact Microsoft support. There's no secret alternate way to do this.

Comment: Those are Microsoft's instructions for Word, Excel and PowerPoint - but this question was about Outlook. They won't work for Outlook as it is not structured the same way.

Answer (score 1):

The add-ins for Outlook are saved in a different way than add-ins for Word, Excel and PowerPoint. When you install a custom add-in from a manifest, the only thing actually installed is the manifest file, which is placed in a subfolder in:

```
/Users/<username>/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Outlook/Data/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Office/16.0/Wef/
```

The actual folder name depends on the installed version of Outlook. For example on my installation, the subfolder is named:

```
{7C3F43ED-AE0C-944A-A24C-7600FF485918}/5mwIVoCDw1ZTUJCywA2uyg==/Manifests/
```

The manifest.xml file is renamed to the value of the  tag and the value of the  tag inside the manifest - like this:

```
  <uuid>_<version>
```

For example if your manifest includes this:

```
<Id>EC13B9A0-5BA2-676A-956B-C583BDC94D5E</Id>
<Version>1.1</Version>
```

It would be named like this:

```
ec13b9a0-5ba2-676a-956b-c583bdc94d5e_1.1.0.0
```

Unfortunately just adding your file to the directory is not enough to fully install the add-in. The next time you open Outlook, the add-in will actually be installed and show up in the ribbon - but after a short while, Outlook will discover that it is not supposed to be there, and it removes the add-in again. Including deleting the file from the file system.

This indicates to me that the installation of the add-in is registered with Microsoft's servers - the same way as when you add an add-in from a URL.